Conditional formatting with OR function, using Row() and Dynamic column number
The column_num is dynamically fetched. Based on that i need to conditional format the cell which mathch the value "yes" or "true". The conditional formatting is not working when it is applied to multiple rows.
I tried below formula and it's not working

=OR(ADDRESS(ROW(), MATCH("column_num", $3:$3, 0))="yes", ADDRESS(ROW(), MATCH("column_num", $3:$3, 0))="true")


Instead of posting a formula that  doesn't work, please edit your question and explain in words what you would like to achieve.

OR and AND with INDIRECT do not seem to work in conditional formatting (seems to be a known phenomenon); so use + for OR or * for AND. When you get a chance, look at the answer.

It looks to me like you are overly complicating a simple conditional formatting scenario. As I interpret your non-working formula, you want to inspect column C of the current row for a value and apply that format to a range of cells.
Just select a range of cells in column C and enter the Conditional formatting formula
=OR($C5="yes",$C5=TRUE)

Apply this CF to only column C to highlight just the cells in that column. Or, to highlight the whole row, apply the format to a range that includes more columns, like in this screenshot

If you want to make the scenario use a variable column number, consider this:

In the screenshot below, cell B2 has the range name column_number.
To apply the conditional formula, select cells A5 to G14 (the cells outlined by a grid.

Apply this conditional formatting formula:
=AND(COLUMN(A5)=column_number,OR(A5="yes",A5=TRUE))

The CF is applied to the selection. There is no need to use a complicated formula to establish the current cell. All you need is a relative reference to the cell that was the active cell when the CF formula has been defined.

Change the column number in cell B2 to, say, 2 and you will see column B has the highlights

COLUMN(A5)=column_number would not be correct if the range starts, for example, from C, right?

@nkalvi Read my post again. The screenshots show working scenarios.

Thanks for getting back. In my interpretation, we need to match column_num with the values specified in the third row. Also, when trying the ADDRESS method, it looks the whole row needs to be highlighted, not just the cell. BTW, you may want to update the second screenshot to match " in cell B2 to, say, 2 and you will see..."

Why it didn't work
We need to use INDIRECT in order to get the content returned by ADDRESS. So the following would work:
Update
OR and AND with INDIRECT do not seem to work in conditional formatting (seems to be a known phenomenon); so use + for OR or * for AND.
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B4), MATCH($B$1, $3:$3, 0)))="yes") 
+ (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B4), MATCH($B$1, $3:$3, 0)))="true")



It is generally recommended that it is best to avoid volatile functions like ADDRESS.
Could you try this:

Select the area for conditional formatting
Remove all rules
Add new rule
Enter the formula, matching

your first cell in the range (B6 in the example)
column_num cell ($B$1 in the example)
List to check 5:5



=OR(INDEX($A$1:$E$9,ROW(B6),MATCH($B$1,$5:$5,0) ) = HSTACK("yes","true",TRUE))

TRUE to capture values entered as TRUE (not as text), please remove it if not applicable.


The above equation simplify. But my secarion is like this.
I need to find a string in row 5. Based on what column it return, i need to look for the curent row() intersection value. The value is checked against multiple values (OR).
I tried something like this with your suggestion but the index won't work on text reference. Do you have any alternate way? Thanks.
OR(INDEX(CONCATENATE(CHAR(64+MATCH("NAME", $5:$5,0)), ":", CHAR(64+MATCH("NAME", $5:$5,0))), ROW()) = HSTACK("yes", "true"))

Only INDIRECT can be used in that manner. Please my update and see whether it helps.
